# importing project into eclipse error

Tags: android

I am having difficulty importing my project into eclipse.  My machine crashed the other day and lost my workspace.  Fortunately I have the complied app (.apk) so I have decompiled it and did all the steps one has to do to get the java files and xml files and so forth.  once that was done I imported the project back into eclipse so I can carry on working on it.  However when I import it now basically its giving errors all over my java files. I tried to clean the project and rebuild but nothing.  it is only the java files the rest is okay (xml and manifest)  any ideas on how to resolve this or do I need to start from scratch?  any help will be appreciated.

image
[image]

as you can see this was correct the first time around and now it says otherwise.  and this is just a start of it, it seems everything is wrong.

okay when I add the project to eclipse instead of import I get this error message now.:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'MyActivity'.
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.AbortIncrementalBuildException
```

Comment: can you be specific by showing any of java file code?

Comment: Yeah, could you give us some details on the error ? If you don't see any clear message then display the error console on eclipse, it should tell you what's missing.

Comment: create a new project in eclipse and drag all files into that project

Comment: @Keithk - Are you getting the compile time errors on switch-case statements only ?

Comment: @VedPrakash - About 90% yes

Comment: @Keithk - Then I doubt that your project is used as a library project in some other project. Check this link- http://tools.android.com/recent/switchstatementconversion

Comment: @VedPrakash - Okay I see, so the best is to rewrite the app then?

Comment: @Keithk - See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I seldom manage to import android project into eclipse by importing as an Android project. If it what you have done, then you should to import as a general project, just as a "project into workspace" , it could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As of **ADT 14**,

> Resource constants in library projects are no longer final.

So the problem seems to be that you have messed up your android properties settings with the other project where you declared this current project to be used as a library project.

Since you have the compile time errors related to `switch-case` and you messed up the settings so first try to be sure that if you can get rid of these compile time errors by just converting the switch-case statements to their equivalent `if-else` ones.

The conversion can be much easy if you are using the user friendly workbench like eclipse.
All you have to do is to point your cursor to `switch` statement in which you are getting the compile time error and then press the shortcut key `Control + 1`. The dialog will open and ask you for the conversion from **switch-case to if-else**. You have to follow that dialog instructions then it will auto convert those `switch-case` statements to `if-else`.

You can also do it manually although it will be a lot of work if there is a lot to change for the whole application.

**For instance (Example)--**

```
int id = view.getId();

    switch (id) {
    case R.id.button1:
        action1();
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        action2();
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        action3();
        break;
}
```

**Conversion to if-else--**

```
int id = view.getId();
if (id == R.id.button1) {
    action1();
} else if (id == R.id.button2) {
    action2();
} else if (id == R.id.button3) {
    action3();
}
```

Once you convert like this just note that if the error still persists.

If the error is still there, the best is to rewrite the app. You can lift off much burden by using the decompiler for the generated .apk file and to use the files wherever applicable.

But as mentioned -- "You made the application, so you knows better as to where to make changes".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

```
IF you have a decompiled the .class.Not all the source code you can obtain.You can get some ideas.
In android it is highly obfuscated.
So all classes and variable seems like.
Log.e,a,b,c,etc like.
We can't just use class,xmls that are decompiled.And just import into the Eclipse IDE.
It will produce lots of errors.
You can get the sane idea of what each and every methods.
As you said you have programmed the app.Then you must have the idea how you programmed.
Now you can just make some corrections.And try it.
```